# Why is `this` the Window object in this JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Having a complete nightmare here, struggling to explain to myself why `this` is the `window` Object?

```
(function () {

    function get () {
        alert(this);
    }

    get();

})();
```

It was my understanding that functions created scope in JS, how come this refers to the `window` Object?

Comment: scope !== this in js. you can turn this into scope using with(), but your're not supposed to.

Comment: It's not in strict mode by the way.

Comment: What did you expect `this` to be? You can't explicitly access the closure of the invoked function expression enclosing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because this is how JavaScript works, [barring strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode).

`this` is `window` unless you explicitly invoke a method on a different object. The code you've posted, `get` is being invoked with no explicit `this`, so it is invoked on `window`.

```
x.method() // "this" will be "x"

method() // "this" will be "window"
```

Comment: May I suggest this link for "how JavaScript works"? http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3

Comment: This is not the case in strict mode. `(function(){ "use strict"; this.x = 5;})();// TypeError` - one of the many reasons strict mode should be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

## The rules for determining `this` in Javascript

**In order of precedence:**

- The function is called with `new`, e.g. `var a = new method()`, causing `this` to be a new, empty object.
- The function is explicitly called with a specific context, using `call`, `apply`, or `bind`, causing `this` to be the context that was used (e.g `method.call(y)` would cause `this` to be `y`)
- The function is called by an object, causing the context of the function to be the calling object (e.g. `x.method()` would cause `this` to be `x`)
- In non-strict mode, `this` defaults to the global object, if none of the other rules are met.  In strict mode, `this` will be undefined.